# Db4o API can't see dynamically loaded Classes in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, classloader, db4o

I seem to be having what I *believe* is a ClassLoader problem using db4o with NetBeans. When I run the exact same code from the terminal with the same jar files from .../jre/lib/ext, everything works fine. The issue is that when I make a native query on some Classes that are loaded at runtime using a ClassLoader, I get an empty List from the database where I should *definitely* be getting a List with some elements (as I said, the same code works fine from the command line). I feel like this may be because the NetBeans ClassLoader works differently than the JVM ClassLoader, but I don't know, I'm certainly no expert on either. Here is the code from my main function.....

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
package gql;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.db4o.*;

public class GQL {
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // GLOBAL VARIABLES
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private static ObjectSet dbObjects;
    private static LinkedList classes = new LinkedList();
    private static String dbPath, classPath;
    private static ObjectContainer db;
    private static ClassLoader coreClassLoader =
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    private static ClassLoader subClassLoader =
            ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // CREATE DATABASE OBJECT
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // If no path to a database is provided on the command line, print
        // error and exit program
        if (args.length < 1) {
           System.err.println("\nError: no database path provided.\n");
           return;
        } else if (args.length > 1) {
           dbPath = args[0];
           // TODO - dubug command line classpath
           classPath = args[1];
           db = Db4o.openFile(dbPath);
        } else {     // We assume that the database Classes are stored somewhere
           dbPath = args[0];    // along the CLASSPATH, and therefore classPath
           classPath = "";      // can be left empty
           db = Db4o.openFile(dbPath);
        }

        System.out.print("GQL> ");

        // The prompt of the interpreter is within a do-while loop, which can
        // be terminated by entering "exit"
        do {
           try {

               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // READ IN QUERY FILE
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // We create a Scanner object to read tokens from the standard in
               // stream - these will be our DLOG files provided by the user
               Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
               String GQLFile = fileScanner.next();

               // Break loop and exit program if user enters "exit"
               if (GQLFile.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
                   break;

               // If the user input is not preceeded by "@" and teminated with
               // ";" then the input is invalid - the user is prompted again
               } else if (!(GQLFile.substring(0,1).equals("@")) ||
                           !(GQLFile.substring(GQLFile.length()-1,
                               GQLFile.length()).equals(";"))) {

                   System.out.println("\nInvalid input.\nUsage:     "
                           + " @filename;\n");
                   System.out.print("GQL> ");
                   continue;

               } else {

                   // Parse out the "@" and ";" from the user's input and send
                   // this to a file Reader object
                   GQLFile = GQLFile.substring(1,GQLFile.length()-1);
               }

               // Now we create a reader object and give it the user's parsed
               // input - in the event of a FileNotFoundException, the user is
               // prompted again
               Reader reader;
               try {
                   reader = new FileReader(GQLFile);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   System.out.println("\nFile " + GQLFile +
                           " does not exist.\n");
                   System.out.print("GQL> ");
                   continue;
               }

               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // PARSE QUERY
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // The parser and Lexer objects are created in the parser.java
               // and Lexer.java files, respectively - The parser takes the
               // Lexer as an argument - the value variable generated by the
               // parse() method will return the topmost grammar construct,
               // which in this case is a Query object
               parser p = new parser(new Lexer(reader));                      

               Query query = (Query) p.parse().value;
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               System.out.println("\n----------------------------Input Query-----" +
                       "-----------------------\n");

               System.out.println("\n                        SUCCESSFUL PARSE   " +
                       "                       \n");

               System.out.println("--------------------------------------" +
                       "------------------------------\n");
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // LOAD ALL CLASSES USED IN DATABASE INTO RUNTIME
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // databse Classes should be kept on the CLASSPATH, or the path
               // to these classes should be provided as a second command line
               // argument
               boolean coreClassesLoaded = loadCoreClasses(coreClassLoader,
                       classPath);
               if (!coreClassesLoaded) {
                   System.err.println("\nError: one or more of core Classes"
                           + "Node, Egge and SimplePath could not be found.\n");
                   db.close();
                   return;
               }
               //
               System.out.println("Core classes loaded.\n");
               boolean subclassesLoaded = query.loadSubclasses(subClassLoader,
                       classPath);
               if (!subclassesLoaded) {
                   System.err.println("\nError: subclasses could not be" +
                           " loaded.\n");
                   db.close();
                   return;
               }
               //
               System.out.println("Subclasses loaded.\n");


               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // MAKE SURE THE DATABASE ACTUALLY CONTAINS SOME OBJECTS AND,
               // IF SO, PUT AN INSTANCE OF EACH CLASS REPRESENTED INTO THE
               // LINKEDLIST CLASSLIST - SINCE WE LOADED THE DATABASE CLASSES
               // INTO THE RUNTIME ENVIRONMENT, OBJECTS RETURNED BY DATABASE
               // QUERIES WILL REMAIN TRUE TO THEIR TYPE; IF WE HADN'T DONE
               // THIS, THESE OBJECTS WOULD BE RETURNED AS TYPE GENERICOBJECT
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               dbObjects = db.queryByExample(Object.class);
               if (dbObjects.hasNext()) {
                  query.addClassesToList(dbObjects, classes);
               } else {
                   System.err.println("\nError: no objects in database.\n");
                   db.close();
                   return;
               }
               //
               System.out.println(classes);

               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // SEMANTIC CHECKS                                             //
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               boolean headArgsAreSet = query.setHeadArgClasses(classes);    
               if (!headArgsAreSet) {                                        
                   db.close();
                   return;                                                   
               }                                                             
               boolean typesMatch = query.checkQueryTypes(db);         
               if (!typesMatch) {                                            
                   db.close();
                   return;
               }              

               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               // EVALUATION
               /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
               query.evaluateQuery(db);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               System.out.println("\nSYNTAX ERROR\n");
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           System.out.print("GQL> ");
        } while (true);

        System.out.println("\nExiting...\n");
        db.close();
    }

    private static boolean loadCoreClasses(ClassLoader coreClassLoader,
            String classPath) {
        try {
            coreClassLoader.loadClass("Node");
            coreClassLoader.loadClass("Edge");
            coreClassLoader.loadClass("SimplePath");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

The strange thing is, the classes I need are definitely getting loaded into the runtime environment, as  I use them to set some Class member variables, for example in the "SEMANTIC CHECKS" section. So it's like the *application* can see the dynamically loaded Classes, but the db4o API/database cannot. Also, I have the Class jar and the db4o jar set up as Netbeans libraries, not just in .../jre/lib/ext. Here's a snippet of the code in the Class where I actually use the db4o native query that's giving me problems...

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

   public void evaluateQuery(ObjectContainer db) {
        if (this.hasPredicate) {
            ;
        } else {
            if (this.isNode) {
                List nodes = db.query(new Predicate() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean match(Node node) {
                        return (node.getName().equals("5"));
                    }
                });
                System.out.println("\n_________________RESULT__________________________");
                System.out.println("\nNode: " + nodes.get(0).getName()
                        //+ ".\n");
            }
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

... if I do the following instead I still get an empty List...

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


   public void evaluateQuery(ObjectContainer db) {
        if (this.hasPredicate) {
            ;
        } else {
            if (this.isNode) {
                List nodes = db.queryByExample(Node.class);
                System.out.println(nodes.size());
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("\nNode: " + nodes.get(i).getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like this is a bug in Linux/Netbeans for Linux/Db4o. I used the exact same source files on a windows box and everything worked fine. I'm pretty disappointed, I don't want to have to use windows for this project. :/

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't see any dynamic class loading problems here. You're using the system's classloader, which should be visible to db4o. You don't even need to load the classes, db4o will do that with the classloaders.

Are you sure that the application picks up the same database? Are you using a relative path?

Btw you can explicitly set the [classloader for db4o](http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/configuration/common/reflector.htm#kanchor76), like this.

```
EmbeddedConfiguration configuration = Db4oEmbedded.newConfiguration();

JdkLoader classLookUp = new ClassLoaderLookup(
        Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(),
        new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file://./some/other/location")}));
configuration.common().reflectWith(new JdkReflector(classLookUp));

ObjectContainer container = Db4oEmbedded.openFile(configuration,"database.db4o");
```

Comment: Yes I'm positive that it's picking up the same database. I just double checked where neatbeans 'looks' for command line arguments to make sure, it's in the top level package directory "gql". I can do a query of Object.class and print out everything that's supposed to be in the database. It's just when I query according to dynamically loaded classes that there's a problem.

Comment: Oh that's cool that you can define a classloader in db4o's configuration. Thanks Gamlor, I'm going to try that and see if it makes any difference.